# Read int from file separated by comma

Tags: java, bufferedreader

I have this code here, that reads numbers from a file and stores them in a String array.

```
        public static void main(String [] args) throws Exception{


             BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("/Users/Tda/desktop/ReadFiles/scores.txt"));

             String line = null;

             while((line = br.readLine()) != null){

               String[] values = line.split(",");

               for(String str : values){
               System.out.println(str);
               }

              }

             System.out.println("");

             br.close();            

         }
```

But if I wanted to store the values from the String array in a int array, how should I do?

The file that I'm reading looks something like this.

```
      23,64,73,26
      75,34,21,43
```

Comment: Do you wish to put all the values in a single int array or do you wish to have a separate int array for each line in the file?

Comment: Actually one array for each line, but one array for all is ok aswell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After `String[] values = line.split(",");`...

```
// new int[] with "values"'s length
int[] intValues = new int[values.length];
// looping over String values
for (int i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
    // trying to parse String value as int
    try {
        // worked, assigning to respective int[] array position
        intValues[i] = Integer.parseInt(values[i]);
    }
    // didn't work, moving over next String value
    // at that position int will have default value 0
    catch (NumberFormatException nfe) {
        continue;
    }
}
```

... and to test:

```
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(intValues));
```

Answer (score 1):

Use parseInt(String) to convert every string to int
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt%28java.lang.String%29

```
int[] intvalues = new int[values.length];
    for (int i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
        intvalues[i] = Integer.parseInt(values[i]);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You would need to parse your `string` into an `int`:

```
 while((line = br.readLine()) != null){

               String[] values = line.split(",");
               int[] values2=new int[values.length];

               for(int i=0; i<values.length; i++){
               try {
               values2[i]= Integer.parseInt(values[i]);
               //in case it's not an int, you need to try catching a potential exception
               }catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                 continue;
               }
               }


 }
```

Comment: It should be values.length in the for loop and not values.length()

Comment: Good catch! Completely missed that.